# Which is better way for data sharing, attaching data to window or making service in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular-services

Title may be not straight forward but I am trying to explain my doubt in details here.

Goal is to find out best way to store and share data in angular Js

First approach

Is to store data as window object like

```
window.myVar ='someValue'
```

And access anywhere in application

Second approach is to make a service and share data

```
   @Injectable()
export class commonDataService{

  constructor() { }

  dataService = {};

  setItem(id, val) {
    this.dataService[id] = val;
  }

  getItem(id) {
    return (this.dataService[id]);
  }

  deleteItem(id) {
    if (this.dataService[id]) {
      delete (this.dataService[id]);
    }
  }

  deleteAll() {
    // delete all properties of this item
    for (const property in this.dataService) {
      if (this.dataService[property]) {
        delete this.dataService[property];
      }

    }
  }

}
```

Now inject this service and keep fetching and updating data using get and set Across application

Out of these two approach which one is better or if any other approach is there in angular or javascript.

Ofcourse data security wise service is better as window object any one can see

What are the merits and demerits of both approach
1. Memory consumption wise
2. Any memory leak inpact
3. Any other performance impact as application grows

Comment: Best practice advice: never touch the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

A centralized service would be the way to go. In fact for large scale applications I would highly recommend ngRx which offers `Store`s that can help maintain the application state. Alternatively for a simpler use case you could implement a centralized service that utilizes Subjects and Observables.

for example.

```
@Injectable()
export class CentralService {
  masterData$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([1,2,3]);

  updateData(newData: number[]): void {
    this.masterData$.next(newData);
  }
}
```